# Trying to put both for loops from csv to txt

Tags: python

```
import csv 

with open("pakalpojumi.csv", mode="r",encoding="utf-8")as fails, open("ProjektsTests.txt","w")as otrsf:
    teksts=csv.reader(fails) 




    for x in teksts:
             if x[0]=="Valsts zemes dienests" and x[4]=="1":
                 print(x)

    

    for y in teksts:
              if y[5]=="2" and y[8]=="0":
                 print(y)



with open("ProjektsTests.txt",mode="a", encoding="utf-8")as file:
    file.write(f"{x}")


fails.close()
```

This is the whole code. Csv is a list and whith x and y i pick the certen rows out of the list. Both x and y do the smae thing, the only diference is the numbers/ words teth x and y is looking for in the csv file.

I don't understand why the code is only reading x and not y, it clames trth y isnt defined when it is, because of it not beeing able to read y I can't put x and y in the txt form. (If i swich them araund and put y on the top then it has no problem reading y)

I tried making x and y in to one single form but it couldn't read y (z=x+y)